# C++ lambda - how to capture function parameter

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a function (fn1) that receives another function (fn2) as parameter. I wish to execute that parameter from within a lambda, which will be passed as argument to yet another function (fn3). Something like this:

```cpp
void fn1(void (*fn2)()) {
  // execute fn2 parameter inside lambda
  fn3([ fn2 ] () { fn2(); });
}

void fn3(void (*lambda)()) {
  // do stuff ...
  lambda();
}
```

If I try to compile this I get the following error:
cannot convert `'fn3(void (*)())::'` to `'void (*)()'` for argument `'1'` to `'void fn1(void (*)())'`

If I simply execute the function inside the lambda (without fn3) it compiles fine.

```cpp
void fn1(void (*fn2)()) {
  [ fn2 ] () { fn2(); }();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Lambda with captures cannot be converted to pointer to function - your lambda captures `f2`. Why not just use template to handle any callable object `template<class F> void fn3(F f){ f(); }` instead.

Comment: if I got it right, I can't pass a lambda that captures something as a parameter to another function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambdas that capture have a state, hence they are fundamentally different from free functions and you cannot cast between the two.

Instead of using function pointers you can change the function to accept any callable:

```
void foo(){}

template <typename T>
void fn3(T t) {
  // do stuff ...
  t();
}

void fn1(void (*fn2)()) {
  // execute fn2 parameter inside lambda
  fn3([ fn2 ] () { fn2(); });
}

int main() {
   fn1(foo); 
}
```

I only modified `fn3` but I would suggest the same for `fn1`.

Comment: like a charm ;)

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas with captures do nor have the conversion to pointer to function.

Instead use std::function like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void fn3( const std::function<void()> &lambda ) 
{
  lambda();
}

void fn1(void (*fn2)()) 
{
  fn3( std::function<void()>( [ fn2 ] () { fn2(); } ) );
}


void fn2() { std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; }

int main() 
{
    fn1( fn2 );
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
```